# Cambiar usuario que crea logs en laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: imagen de la terminal carpeta logs de laravel]

Tengo un problema con los logs que crea laravel, los nuevo logs los crea con el usuario root y tengo que cambiarlos manualmente (chown...) deberían crearse con el www-data como podría hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Qué usuario tiene el servidor web?

Comment: Ejecutando ps -aux | grep -i nginx.service dice que es "root" y ejecutando ps -aux | grep -i nginx es "www-data"